# Как очистить setInterval?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как я понял clearInterval останавливает таймер по его ID, но как очистить setInterval из памяти программы?

Comment: В каком смысле "очистить"? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management - оно само чистит всё ненужное.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё что остаётся после использования `clearInterval` это id таймера, который до этого существовал. Вы можете присвоить переменной, где хранится это значеие `null`, чтобы от вашего таймера не осталось и следа =).

Но в этом нет смысла, ничего не поменяется